# Nota de 15 estudiantes y eliminar la menor nota

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda de como puedo eliminar la menor nota y también poder añadir 4 notas, es que se me dificulto esa parte

```
    def promediar(codigo, *nota):
  suma = 0
  for n in nota:
    suma+= n
  return "Codigo del estudiante {} el promedio : {}".format(codigo, round(suma/4/100, 1))

print(promediar("123", 81,25,33,41))
```

Comment: puedes pasar todo a una lista y ordenar de menor a mayor y eliminar el primer elemento

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al utilizar `*args` estas recibiendo parámetros de forma variable pero esos parámetros se almacenan en una tupla, esto nos da una ventaja ya que podemos hacer varias cosas.

Para sacar el promedio de los elementos podemos usar la función `sum()` y luego dividir entre su longitud `len(nota)`
Ahora para eliminar el menor solo debemos de utilizar la función `sorted()` la cual ordena de menor a mayor, por tal razón el menor se encuentra en la posición `0` así que lo eliminariamos fácilmente.

Para agregar elementos podemos usar el método `append()` de las listas, y es que `sorted()` nos retorna una lista, por lo que podemos usar todos los métodos de estas.

```py
def promedio(codigo,  *nota):
  prom = sum(nota)/len(nota)
  #ordenamos
  notas_ord= sorted(nota)
  notas_ord.pop(0) #borramos
  print(notas_ord) #imprimimos
  #agregamos elementos
  #notas_ord.append(10)
  return f"Codigo del estudiante {codigo} el promedio : {prom}" #usamos f strings
```